# Clear logs in native Docker on Mac

Tags: macos, logging, docker

I want to get rid of huge container log files on my docker env.

I have problem finding them when running native Docker on a Mac. I am not using docker-machine (virtualbox) thing. My docker version is 1.13.1.

When I do

```
docker inspect <container-name>
```

I see there is

```
"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log
```

But there is not even directory /var/lib/docker on my mac (host).

I have also looked in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/
```

but didn't find any container specific loggings there.

I could use tail, but it is not that convenient always to me.

So the question is, how can I clear the log files of my containers on my native Docker Mac environment.

Answer (score 17):

This will remove all your docker logs **in macOS**.

```
echo "rm /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log" | nc -U -w 0 ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/debug-shell.sock
```

Comment: This worked for me
`macOS Monterey 12.6.1`
`Docker Desktop 4.15.0`

Answer (score 16):

#### Docker daemon runs in a separate VM, so in order to clear logs you should do the following steps:

First, you can find the log path inside the VM, with:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' NAME|ID
```

You can connect to the VM with `screen`

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

Here you can simply use output redirection to clear the log

```
> /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_ID-json.log
```

And finally you can detach the screen with hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: awesome, I was doing a Reset > Remove all data, because one of my container overlays kept growing like crazy, but this is much better! Knew it had something to do with log files. Great find!

Comment: in my case, the vm path is ` ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Comment: you can also use `truncate -s 0 LOG_PATH` to clear the log

Comment: As of 3.2.2, `tty` file doesn't exist there anymore (neither the location from the answer or the comment update).

Answer (score 16):

I added the following to my bash_profile.
it gets the logpath for the docker container, opens a screen to the docker machine and deletes the logfile.

```
clearDockerLog(){
dockerLogFile=$(docker inspect $1 | grep -G '\"LogPath\": \"*\"' | sed -e 's/.*\"LogPath\": \"//g' | sed -e 's/\",//g')
rmCommand="rm $dockerLogFile"
screen -d -m -S dockerlogdelete ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
screen -S dockerlogdelete -p 0 -X stuff $"$rmCommand"
screen -S dockerlogdelete -p 0 -X stuff $'\n'
screen -S dockerlogdelete -X quit
}
```

use as follows:

```
clearDockerLog <container_name>
```

Comment: ty. this was helpful

Comment: I also had to change the screen path to ` ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Comment: As of 3.2.2, `tty` file doesn't exist there anymore (neither from the answer or the comment)

Answer (score 8):

This is the only solution that worked for **macOS 10.14**

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host NAME nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i -- sh -c 'truncate -s0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log'
```

Replace NAME with your container name

Hope this helps

Comment: As of September 2021, this seems to be the simplest way to clear the docker container logs on MacOS.

Comment: August 2022 - this still works for macOS 10.15

Comment: This just doesn't work on OSX 12.

Comment: As of May 2023 this is working nicely, in macOS Ventura 13.1. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, at least from the commandline: `screen $(cat ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty)`

This might work better with the script if the above doesn't: `screen /dev/ttys000`

[gist with more things to try](https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389)

Comment: As of 3.2.2, `tty` file doesn't exist there anymore.